# C++11: reference-to-void?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is this C++11 program ill-formed?

```
typedef void& rv;

int main() {}
```

I couldn't find anything disallowing it in the standard (looked in 3.9.2 and 8.3.2).

Clang says "cannot form a reference to 'void'", gcc says "cannot declare reference to ‘void’"

I would have expected [dcl.ref]/5 to give such a restriction, if it were intended.

Are the implementations just "reading between the lines" because such a type can never be used in an object definition?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quoting from the C++11 standard (emphasis mine):

> #### 8.3.2 References
>
> <sup>1</sup> [...] A declarator that specifies the type
>   “**reference** to cv **void**” is **ill-formed**.

---

As a side tidbit of info, this rule has been taken advantage by the [N3421 `greater<>` proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3421.txt) (which was already accepted to be included into the future C++14 standard) by having `void` as the default template argument.

> B. The technique of using default template arguments and explicit
>   specializations for `void` was chosen for its non-intrusiveness. `greater<void>`
>   isn't valid C++11 (it would attempt to form a reference to `void`, forbidden by
>   8.3.2 [dcl.ref]/1). Additionally, while users are permitted to specialize
>   Standard Library machinery (17.6.4.2.1 [namespace.std]/1), such specializations
>   must involve user-defined types.

---

Maybe I'm just a bit more indulged into these mind games, but for the rationale of why this rule is enforced -- and I must state that this is just my own humble opinion -- consider the following code:

```
sizeof(double&);   // Results in double's size

using foo_ref = foo&;
sizeof(foo_ref);   // Results in foo's size

sizeof(void);      // Error! void has no size!
sizeof(void&);     // Error! Tries to get the size of void
```

Most importantly, keep in mind that references are just aliases of other objects, and you cannot have an object of type `void`.

Comment: It was hiding after an example and a note, hehe.  Thanks.

Comment: Regarding rationale: Keep in mind this is ok `struct C; typedef C& r;`.  Even though `sizeof(C)` and `sizeof(C&)` are ill-formed.  We say `C` and `void` are incompletely-defined types. ([basic.types]/5).  The difference is that `C` can be completed later in the translation unit, whereas `void` can never be completed.  Hence `reference to void` can never be initialized, and so it isn't really a useful type.

Answer (score 2):

A reference to a `void` means the data pointed to, which doesn't have a type, therefore it cannot be referenced in any meaningful way.

A reference is a reference to an instance of some type, which cannot be of type `void`.